# How to export multiple html tables and multiple d3 generated graphs into a single pdf

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, d3.js, jstl

Basically I have multiple tables that are generated in html (also the data may vary depends on how much data are in the database, so I want the tables on pdf to be scalable as well, meaning no fixed size.) In addition, I have a d3 generated graph too on the same page.

What I want to know is..is there any way to turn everything displayed on the page into a pdf like a screenshot? I know there is phantomJS but it requires you to install and deploy on the local environment, and our project won't allow it.. so is there any 3rd party libraries that I can import and use to export them into a single PDF?

Please help

Comment: Take a look at jspdf https://parall.ax/products/jspdf

Comment: yeah, I am also looking into it, but there is no working example for me to follow, so I'm still trying to configure around to make it work for the table part. However, I haven't seen any graph solutions from jspdf yet, if there is 1, please do let me know. Again, thank you for the quick reply :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Using SaveSvg.js

https://gist.github.com/enjoylife/0ae74717a29862c5d8c5

and using jspdf was able to make it work

d3.select("#save").on("click", function(){
  var html = d3.select("svg")
        .attr("version", 1.1)
        .attr("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")
        .node().parentNode.innerHTML;

  //console.log(html);
  var imgsrc = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,'+ btoa(html);
  var img = '<img src="'+imgsrc+'">'; 
  d3.select("#svgdataurl").html(img);

    var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas"),
        context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    var image = new Image;
    image.src = imgsrc;
    image.onload = function() {
      context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);

      //save and serve it as an actual filename
    binaryblob();

      var a = document.createElement("a");
      a.download = "sample.png";
      a.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

    /* Added as png to jspdf */

         var doc = new jsPDF();
   doc.addImage(  a.href, "png", 0,0); 
   doc.save("test.pdf");

       var pngimg = '<img src="'+a.href+'">'; 
       d3.select("#pngdataurl").html(pngimg);

      a.click();
    };

});
```

jspdf alignment and css is good

http://plnkr.co/edit/nNSvHL8MZcT6nNKg9CG9?p=preview